# Android : htm.fromhtm() remove blank line from under H1, H2,H3,H4,H5,H6 tag

Tags: android, html, header, styles

I am displaying of my HTML code in my textview and using html.fromhtml(). However, when comes to display h1 tag. It must have empty line after h1.  I try to fix it by adding . But I understand that html.fromhtml() does not support   class. May I know is it any solution to remove empty line after h1 in html.fromhtml()? The following is my sample code

```
 title="<h1>Human Resource</h1>";
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be a blank space after < h1 > tags. Just like using < p > tags.

You could replace < h1 > tag programically:

```
title="<h1>Human Resource</h1>";
title = title.replace("<h1>", "<b>");
title = title.replace("</h1>", </b></br>");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
```